# When i use row inside container i get indent between it's two block's but i can't do it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When i use row inside container i get indent between it's two block's but i can't do it.

I am going to clear indent between div .container and div .row. How I can do it. Htpl me,please
Now i get some like this:

[image]

my layout is given below:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="firstSection">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be abit more clearer. Add a jsFiddle to your problem.

Comment: Check the padding/margins of the two containers.